# Android view pager with tab layout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

i have implemented viewpager for image slider with tablayouts as indicator but it seems that i can't make any padding between the dots ,this the layout for pager

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/PlacesPageBanner">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/placesPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMaxWidth="7dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

code for layout containing the dots(tab_selector)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_selected"
    android:state_selected="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_default"/>
```

Comment: @nvi9 i have added the layout

Comment: Try set android:right="anyDp" to your item in layout

Comment: not working i have tried it

Comment: Hmm, why do you set app:tabMaxWidth="7dp"  at TabLayout?

Comment: because the dots appears too large so i set their height

Comment: Maybe try to increase tabMaxWidth? If i understand your problem correctly..

Comment: i try it , it only controls the height of the dots

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your `@drawable/tab_indicator_selected` and `@drawable/tab_indicator_default`. Providing the xml code for those would be helpful to find your issue.

Here's how I did it:

**Tab indicator selected**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="8dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Tab indicator default**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="5dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
```